# Angular Select Default value not being set

Tags: angularjs, select, default-value, ng-init

I am displaying a select like this

```
 <select name="dropdown1" ng-model="$parent.selected"
                ng-init="$parent.selected = $parent.selected || keyValueList[0].Key" 
                ng-options="o.Key as o.Value for o in keyValueList"
                class="form-control"></select>
```

I want the model to be the hold the key and to display the value in the dropdown. This works fine and when I save the the page $scope.selected is the key which I want.

However when I load the page and set $scope.selected to a key in the keyValueList the associated value is not displayed. Infact no value is displayed and there's an empty item at the top of the dropdown.

How can I set the default value of the dropdown by using the key in  $scope.selected?

Comment: you haven't provided enough of the surrounding code to really explain what you are trying to accomplish, but whenever I see `$parent` I always look for a better way to deal with it, and `ng-init` is [almost never a good idea](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!);  using `ng-init` and `$parent` together in one statement definitely feels like there is something missing.

Comment: I believe $parent has to used because this is a partial view (ng-include) which is creating a new scope. "$parent.selected"  changes " $scope.selected"  when an item is selected. Please explain what more information you would need, I thought it was clear.

Comment: it looks like you're attempting to set the parent scope's selected value. If it is truly $scope.selected, use 'selected = selected || ....'

Comment: if your project is using nested views as a regular practice, you should probably consider using the `ControllerAs` syntax instead of `$scope` to avoid issues with parent/child scopes.  Another possibility is to create a directive for your nested content.  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2740-replacing-nginclude-with-component-directives-in-angularjs.htm.  Either approach can eliminate `$parent`, and the need to set a value on the inner scope to a value on the outer scope, which is what you are *trying* to do with `ng-init`, though this isn't really what that directive was designed for.

Comment: as for troubleshooting your current issue, you should use the browser console to inspect the HTML output that is generated for the select statement;  The empty item will actually represent a value that can't be found in the option list, and inspecting the value that is being assigned vs what you are trying to assign it to will help you to identify what isn't functional.